# how can I inject a repository from a givin entity

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I'm using Nestjs with TypeORM, and I want to create a class that receives an entity and creates a repository from it (without providing the default datasource)

in Nestjs we can inject the repository like this

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(MyEntity)
    private repo: Repository<MyEntity>
  ) {}
}
```

I want to make something like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyRepository<Entity extends EntityClassOrSchema> {
  constructor(
    private entity: Entity,
    // this.entity here has not defined yet
    @InjectRepository(this.entity) private repo: Repository<Entity>
  ) {}
}
```